# Let $A_n(x)$ be the $ n{\times}n$ matrix whose entries are $x^{\max(i,j)}$, find the max of $\det A_n(x)$ on the closed interval $[0,1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I tried row reducing this matrix, and got that it is row equivalent to a lower triangular matrix of terms $(1-x)$.
This would give determinant $(1-x)^n$, which in turn would imply the maximum of $\det A_n(x)$ attains a maximum at $x=0$? This is just a zero matrix?

Is this correct? In that case is the determinant for all other values of x less than $0$?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

A quick "sanity check": if we let $x = 0$, your formula gives the determinant as $1$. But the determinant of the zero matrix is $0$, so something has gone wrong.

Let's write it out:
\begin{equation*}
 A_n(x) =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  x & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 & \dotsm \\
  x^2 & x^2 & x^3 & x^4 & \dotsm \\
  x^3 & x^3 & x^3 & x^4 & \dotsm \\
  x^4 & x^4 & x^4 & x^4 & \dotsm \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Now for the row reduction let's subtract $x$ times the row above it from each row, starting from the bottom. Then
\begin{align*}
 \det A_n(x) &=
 \begin{vmatrix}
  x & \dotsm \\
  0 & x^2 - x^3 & \dotsm \\
  0 & 0 & x^3 - x^4 & \dotsm \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & x^4 - x^5 & \dotsm \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
 \end{vmatrix} \\
 &= x^{n(n + 1)/2}(1 - x)^{n - 1}
\end{align*}
Does that help?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I had subtracted x times the row below from each row and had clearly mad a mistake along the way.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's all wrong.  For example, in the $2 \times 2$ case, 
$$\det \pmatrix{x & x^2\cr x^2 & x^2\cr} = x^3- x^4$$
which has its maximum at $x=3/4$.